# How to generate Random Number that are skewed distributed between 0 and 1

Tags: java

I would like to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 that are skewed distributed. Any help for me to do that on JAVA?

Comment: Can you show to us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Skewed according to what distribution?  http://jdistlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Use italic font.